# git push option in pre receive hook

Tags: python, git, gitlab

I am writing a git pre-receive hook in python and would like to receive the arguments passed from the command line in the push-option.

```
git push -push-option='my option'
```

How do I access the push option inside of my pre-receive hook?

Answer (score 6):

See the [githook documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#pre-receive).

> The number of push options given on the command line of `git push
>   --push-option=...` can be read from the environment variable `GIT_PUSH_OPTION_COUNT`, and the options themselves are found in
>   `GIT_PUSH_OPTION_0`, `GIT_PUSH_OPTION_1`,…​ If it is negotiated to not use
>   the push options phase, the environment variables will not be set. If
>   the client selects to use push options, but doesn’t transmit any, the
>   count variable will be set to zero, `GIT_PUSH_OPTION_COUNT=0`.